# 802.1.x GPO configuration with restriction by computers and users

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, wifi, 802.1

802.1.x configuration possible using Machine Policy GPO. So, typical scenario is creating security group for computers and applying our policy with 802.1.x to this group. After this all machines from this group will be able to use defined 802.1.x configuration. This schema gives ability to restrict working with Wi-Fi by computers.
We want give permission to Wi-Fi connecting not only by computer but also by user. We want have user group in active directory and only users for this group can use Wi-Fi on computers mentioned above.
But this isn’t easy because of our users are not administrators so we can’t use some logon script in User Policy which can be modify Wi-Fi configuration. 
How can these requirements be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a misunderstanding about wireless network policies.

Each "Profile" (SSID) specified in a wireless network policy has an Authentication Mode setting that controls computer versus user authentication.

[image: New Profile properties dialog]

While these policies *are* applied to computers they can be configured to require user authentication.